# How can I write a string inside of an input?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem of printing a string inside an input. I made a *for* loop for automatic numbering based on how many elements that the user wants to input.

```
list = []
n = int(input("How many elements you want to input: "))
for i in range(0, n):
   element = int(input(i+1))
   if n == element:
      print("hello")
      break
list.append(element)
```

For example, I inputted 3 in the number of elements. I want to make my program output be like this:

1. input
2. input
3. input

(*input* is the user will type once the number is shown)

But my program looks like:

1input

2input

3input

I just want to work up with the design, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You only want to print n times the input given by the user is that right ? Because I suspect the 2nd for loop to be useless

Comment: I edited it. I did not notice that I have another loop

Comment: Do you want the "etc." to be printed too ?

Comment: Ah no. It is not needed. I just stay it like that so whatever the user input, I just want to print out the numbers. I just deleted the "etc" to avoid confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "work up"? Can you elaborate? Preferably, by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68556678/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called string formatting, and you might use `.format` by replacing

```
element = int(input(i+1))
```

using

```
element = int(input("{}. ".format(i+1)))
```

or using so-called f-strings (this requires Python 3.6 or newer):

```
element = int(input(f"{i+1}. "))
```

If you want to know more, I suggest reading [realpython's guide](https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/).

Comment: Tried the 2nd solution and it worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try:
input(str(i+1)+'. ')

This should append a point and a space to your Text. It converts the number of the input to a String, at which you can append another String, e.g. '. '.

Comment: This also worked! Tried to change it manually but when I copied, this work! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the input in the loop to something like this:

```
element = int(input(str(i+1) + ". "))
```

Comment: This worked! I just forgot something that caused an error but this also worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Convert `i+1` to a string and concatenate a `.` to it and accept input.

Note: Do ***not*** use `list` as a variable name. It is a Python reserved word.

```
lst = []
n = int(input("How many elements you want to input: \n"))
for i in range(n):
   element = int((input(str(i+1) + '. ')))
   if n == element:
      print("hello")
      break
lst.append(element)
```

```
How many elements you want to input: 
5
1. 1
2. 6
3. 7
4. 4
5. 6
```

Comment: Thank you the additional information about the list. I made a change and this worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("How many elements you want to input: "))
for i in range(0, n):
      print(str(i+1) + ". " + str(n))
```

This should do.

I used the same code shape as yours, and that way it is easier for you to understand.